BQ --> Scheduled Query ---> @run_time param (BUG?!)
I've BQ Scheduled query as follows:
select 
  current_timestamp() as utc_time, 
  @run_time as run_time

--> run every 1h interval, results appended to a table.
I schedule a manual backfill as follows:

but the result I get is as follows:

I expected run_time col to be (at the hour, instead :43)
-- 2024-05-02 03:00:00 UTC
-- 2024-05-02 02:00:00 UTC
-- 2024-05-02 01:00:00 UTC
is it a BUG?

From the provider side of view, it would be not a good performance idea to run all the backfill from all users at the same time.

Samuel, thank you for comment. this is just a test i did to understand how @run_time parameter is injected. I ran the tests again, and find each time the manual run is scheduled at xx:43 (instead exact at the hour!)

Hi Vibhor, is it the first time you are facing this issue or you have faced this earlier as well ?

@DhirajSingh  i have not tried before, so i'm not aware it existed or not. I've only recently been interested in "@run_time" param feature, so was just exploring how it works before taking it into use. the issues seems to be related to backfills only

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
